# Updating meteor collection with objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to update my meteor collection with a set of objects.

This is what I tried:

```js
Checklists.update({_id: idChecklist}, {
    $addToSet: {
      "domaine": {
        label: label,
        actionsDomaine: checklistActions
      }
    }

  },
  {
    getAutoValues: true
  }
);
```

The label field is inserted just fine. However, in the `actionsDomaine` field, which originally contained an array of objects, only the structure of the object is stored in the database, as in the following figure:

[image: Windows shell is lame]

Comment: Well, the obvious question is, what is `checklistActions`?

Comment: It's an array of objects

Comment: Please post an example. Should work with normal object.

Comment: It's the same issue with a normal object. I tried with $each and now it gives me this error: update failed: Error: Actions domaine must be an array. I have this in my Shema:     actionsDomaine:{
      type: [Schemas.action],
      optional:true
    }

Comment: This could be a side-effect of SimpleSchema or Collection2. Try setting the `filter` option to `false`. Also, you should probably post your schema and try to run it without collection2 in order to isolate the issue.